# Dynamically allocate memory for multi-dimensional string

Tags: c++

How to dynamically allocate memory for two dimensional string as below.

```
struct sample {
    int i;
    std::string arrray [10][10];
};
```

How to dynamically allocate memory for the below one?

```
struct sample {
    int i;
    std::string **arrray;
};
```

Comment: can you just use std:vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one doesn't require memory allocation (when you declare C style arrays in structs the compile will allocate space for them inside the struct).

The second is a fairly standard 2D array.

```
arrray = new string*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)  
    arrray[i] = new string [10];
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Use std::vector to hold string pointers;

Step 2: Use your own defined class(vector container) to encapsulate the vector;

Step 3: Override 2-demention operator[], mapping 2D subscript to std::vector size;

Step 4: Now question is, how to manipulate a 2D subscript? You can define another "friend class", the vector container's [] returns a friend class, and the friend class also has a [] which returns the value inside the std::vector.

Dont forget the member function to change size.